# How to add and subtract quantity in a recyclerview?

Tags: android, cart, product-quantity

```
product_quantity = productArrayList.get(position).getQuantity();
        holder.display_quantity.setText(String.valueOf(product_quantity));


        //        holder.selected_quantity.setText("Selected Quantity: " + String.valueOf(productArrayList.get(position).getQuantity()));

                /*
                * When the select quantity button is pressed in the Cart Fragment via this activity( that is the recyclerview )
                * it shows a dialog which allows the user to change the quantity. The quantity interaction has been done in the CartQuantityActivity.
                * */

        holder.btn_add_quantity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                product_quantity++;
                if (product_quantity > 4) {
                    product_quantity = 4;
                }
                cartRef.child(cartlistKeys.get(position)).child("quantity").setValue(product_quantity);
                productArrayList.get(position).setQuantity(product_quantity);
                holder.display_quantity.setText(String.valueOf(product_quantity));

            }
        });
        holder.btn_subtract_quantity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                product_quantity--;
                if (product_quantity < 1) {
                    product_quantity = 1;
                }
                cartRef.child(cartlistKeys.get(position)).child("quantity").setValue(product_quantity);
                productArrayList.get(position).getQuantity();
                holder.display_quantity.setText(String.valueOf(product_quantity));

            }
        });
```

https://ibb.co/cQst76

https://ibb.co/edZ9Em

I have tried many things but cannot understand why the code does not work for incrementing and decrementing the quantity. I have seen many questions in stackoverflow but none were in android studio. Btw i am using firebase as my backend.
This code snippet is from Recyclerview adapter onbindviewholder method.

Comment: read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: have you checked the value of `cartListkeys.get(position)`? also try 'addOnCompleteListener' for check issue

Comment: Post your code as **text**. **Images of code are totally useless**.

Comment: I have given all the data in the form of images as i was having problems with the formatting of the text in stackoverflow .

Comment: every time when you press the button then in place of creating another variable please make the change by getting the quantity value and notify the adapter.

Comment: Again, post your code **as text**. Nobody's going to help you otherwise.

Comment: But i am not creating a variable but just updating it by the set quantity pojo method.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to make the product_quantity & productArrayList as public variable of the class. I am not sure about how did you define it as your code is not showing that.